# Exchange 2010 OWA could not load assembly after SP3 install

Tags: exchange-2010

We updated our exchange 2010 server (running on Windows 2008 R2) to SP3 by downloading and running the Service Pack provided by Microsoft. After doing that we are unable to connect to any of the websites (OWA, ActiveSync, and so on).

We get yellow .net error screens that say

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Security,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

The assembly name is different for each website. Having a look at the Bin folder for the websites and the GAC folder I noticed that the version number is `14.03.0123.03`, not `14.0.0.0`.

I think the dll's were updated as part of SP3. I have tried removing and re-adding the OWA website but the same problem happens.

Did I miss a step in the install? How can I fix the websites?

---

UPDATE

Sorry, I forgot to mention I don't have Outlook available to test at the moment - we normally use either OWA or ActiveSync on Mobiles.

Also I have tried testexchangeconectvity.com and have confirmed that I am receiving mail, I just can't access it at the moment.

---

Update 2:

I've tried installing the Client Access role on the Mailbox server and this works (although it is not ideal). I've tried uninstalling and re-installing on the original Client Access Server but still get the same error. I've also tried removing and creating new-OWAVirtualDirectory

---

Update 3:
Error details:
[image: error message]

```
Server Error in '/owa' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Net, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Net, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Net, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Net, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +62
   System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +42
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +77
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +105
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +64

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Net, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +11189037
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +78
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1891
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +166
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +382

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Net, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11318198
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4348404




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5420; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420
```

Comment: Have you rebooted since the update? It's not requested, but I had to reboot after SP3 on my lab server to get some things working again.

Comment: yep, a couple of times

Comment: what version did you update from? There is a fix in SP2 that tends to break OWA and require you to run a sciprt to bring OWA back.

Comment: coming from SP2.

Comment: Set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. This will give you further diagnostic info. Also paste output (removing confidential data) using get-OWAVirtualDirectory | fl

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a web.config problem. Check to see if you have web.config.nul or web.config.bak files in that folder. Save the current config and try to revert to one of the others.

If that does not work, looks at what the current authentication settings are for OWA in IIS and make sure they match the correct config.

edit: Also get the full log for the page please. Enable detailed errors.

Go to iis --> the website OWA folder is on --> error pages --> edit feature settings --> detailed errors for local request and custom....

Comment: Thanks @Sarge. I know it's a problem with the web.config, I'm pretty sure the error is because I have version 14.03.0123 dll's not 14.0.0.0 that the web.config if looking for. I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Picture to small copy and paste into code field.

Comment: sorry, forgot to check that. Done now

Comment: Just to make sure you tired to use a backup of the web.config right? Also you need to really check your web.config for mistakes in path etc. Possible its looking for things in the wrong place. DIR paths can get screwed up.

Comment: yes. The backup one gives a slightly shorter error but still says it can't find version 14.0.0.0.

Comment: Ok, can you use ECP with admin account? or same error?

Comment: different dll (Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Security), same error

Comment: Can you recover C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\OWA and restart IIS?

Comment: In the process of doing all of the ClientAccess folders now.

Comment: Did you try to access cas from localhost btw? You dont want to restore all Clientaccess folders just the one causing problems.

Comment: Another one for you, i noticed you said you recreate the OWA virtual folder. Did you use Exchange powershell to do so? Not manually correct?